# Azure Container Registry throws exception when building

Tags: azure, acr

I'm trying to follow the tutorials at MS Learn about Containers in Azure. I'm trying to push a docker image to my recently created azure container registry I'm using the **az acr build** command in the Azure CLI, I'm also using a docker file. After running the command I get this message in the console "Packing source code into tar to upload..." then after a couple of minutes I get this:

`[WinError 5] Access is denied: '.\\AppData\\Local\\Application Data'`

I did a little research and it's supposed that's a junction folder in Win 10 which means it only exists for backwards compatibility, it only redirects you to the new location Microsoft uses.

Anyone happen to have had this error?

I also tried to modify permissions to the Application Data folder but no matter which permissions it has it still throws the same exception.

**UPDATE**

The tutorial I'm trying to follow along is in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/build-and-store-container-images/3-build-container-image). 
I also tried to use the `--verbose` flag of the **az acr build** command and the error is being thrown in this file ```cli.azure.cli.core.util````. I looked over the azure cli github project and found the file but I'm not as good developer to figured out what's going on.

Comment: I didn't meet this error. But I recommend you do not use the OS disk to store personal things. Just use another disk such as D and then run the command in the exact folder.

Comment: @CharlesXu The problem is that I'm not using that folder explicitly. It seems that the command itself is the one that is using that folder internally since I'm only doing **az acr build --registry $ACR_NAME --image helloacrtasks:v1 .** this command. Let me update the question to point to the tutorial I'm being following just to give more context.

Comment: Where do you execute the command? You need to run it in the source directory which contains the Dockerfile.